# GFCI outlet goes from red to green randomly

Tags: gfci

I have GFCI outlets that I occasionally catch glowing red, and they seem to change to green almost instantly shortly afterward. I also finally caught one in the act of going from green to red to green where the red phase lasted for just a second. I just wanted to understand if there is anything of concern with these outlets? They seem to work fine but and they trip when I press Test (light goes out completely), but I can’t seem to find anything online about the light cycling from green to red to green again

Comment: What make and model are your GFCIs? (If you can't figure it out, get us detailed photos of the front and back of one, with the breaker for that circuit turned off ofc)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - another answer suggested it is regular self checks so I will choose to believe this is the answer unless the outlets start to malfunction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that it's a newer GFCI outlet that does self-checks on a regular basis, and I would guess that the brief flashing red indicates that it's doing its self check.

Comment: See for example Leviton https://blog.leviton.com/gfci-status-indicator-light

Comment: I would concur. The way to confirm it would be to find the model number (by pulling the outlet from the wall, but not disconnecting the wiring - turn the power off first), then looking up the brand/model number on the internet. The instruction manual should confirm that this is the case.

Comment: That’s probably it - thanks so much for your input

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard for the meaning of lights on GFCI receptacles.

Consult the instructions for your particular model of GFCI for the meaning of the lights.